# How to find the features names of the coefficients using StackingClassifier + Logistic Regression (binary classification)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, mlxtend

I am trying to use StackingClassifier with Logistic regression (Binary Classifier).
Sample code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from mlxtend.classifier import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

y[y == 2] = 1 #Make it binary classifier

LR1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
LR2 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
LR3 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
LR4 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
LR5 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')


clfs1= [LR1, LR2]
clfs2= [LR3, LR4, LR5]

cls_=[]
cls_.append(clfs1)
cls_.append(clfs2)

sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=sum(cls_,[]), 
    meta_classifier=LogisticRegression(penalty='l1'), use_probas=True, average_probas=False)

sclf.fit(X, y)

sclf.meta_clf_.coef_ #give the weight values
```

For each classifier, Initial logistic regression gives a probability value for two classes. As I am using stacking 5 classifiers, `sclf.meta_clf_.coef_` gives 10 weights values.

> array([[-0.96815163,  1.25335525, -0.03120535,  0.8533569 , -2.6250897 ,
>            1.98034805, -0.361378  ,  0.00571954, -0.03206343,  0.53138651]])

I am confused about the order of weight values. means

- Are the 1st two values `(-0.96815163,  1.25335525)` for first logistic regression `LR1`?
- Are the 2nd two values `(-0.03120535,  0.8533569)` for first logistic regression `LR2`?

I want to find out which values are for which Logistic Regression (LR) for the stacking classifier.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is:

> array([[-0.96815163, 1.25335525, -0.03120535, 0.8533569 , -2.6250897 ,
>   1.98034805, -0.361378 , 0.00571954, -0.03206343, 0.53138651]])

Then,

-0.96815163, 1.25335525: the probability of 0 and 1 for LR1

-0.03120535, 0.8533569: the probability of 0 and 1 for LR2

-2.6250897, 1.98034805: the probability of 0 and 1 for LR3

-0.361378, 0.00571954: the probability of 0 and 1 for LR4

-0.03206343, 0.53138651: the probability of 0 and 1 for LR5